# Reuniting in After Life for unnatural death

Tags: karma, death

1.Does two suicide soul (two person who committed suicide but not at a same time) can meet in after life?

2.Do soul recognize each other after death?

3.Do they hold any memory of this earthly life? (referring to unnatural-suicide)

Comment: Nope Souls will loose memory there mentioned in scriptures it wont take and reunite, because karma, kala calculation is different for different jiva.. prethatva is hellish because the jiva will suffer not able to eat but huger, thirsty but not able to drink.. more suffering then current life.. instead help those who are in need do it as service to lord himself will console ones own self and deceased Those who commit suicide are Dhur atma by default because they didn't put the god given body to right use

Answer (score 1):

They may not meet. Why should they? AS per Swami Shivananda souls may come together(what they call as love) because of past birth attachments. It is there in his book (Bliss Divine).
Generally they don't hold memory unless they are souls like Jada Bharata. There is a category of people who do remember their past birth. I forgot which one(name).